# Which database management system type to choose for price tracking?

Tags: database-design

I'm writing a price tracking application.

Every day I need to store price information about ~15M products. (So it's about 15M * 365  = 5.5B records per year).

One product has many prices over history. My main table (if I opt for a SQL DBMS) should include the following attributes:

- `product_id` (8bytes int)
- `price` (4bytes int) can be `NULL`
- `date` (only date without time since daily update)
- `currency` (3byte string)

E.g. (9223372036854, 85.41, 14-01-2019, "USD")

I don't want to mark the latest price as 'active' or something, so I'm interested only in price history itself. The database should have high IO throughput (~1000 simultaneous reads).

Queries I'm planning to run:

- Get all price for the specific `product_id` for the specific time range
- Basic math operations like `min`, `max`, `avg`

So, I am curious:

- Should I stick to a SQL DBMS (Postgres) or use some NoSQL product (e.g. Amazon Redshift)
- Which DBMS can you recommend?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest building a test system using whatever DBMS you're most familiar with.  As speed is a mission-critical requirement, I would put the data on an NVMe SSD, and load it up with as much fake data as you can create, then put that through a rigorous set of tests.

Back-of-the-envelope calculations suggest you'll need around 100 GB of space for a years-worth of data, so a 1 TB NVMe SSD should suffice.  Of course, if data redundancy is a concern, you may want two, with data being mirrored between them.

PostgreSQL should have no difficulty handling your data.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are very comfortable using a relational database but need to optimize it specifically for time-series data. There's an app for that!

[Timescale](https://www.timescale.com/) is an extension of PostgreSQL. I'm not affiliated with the product, nor have I used it in production environments. But it does look interesting.